# Boolean operations in lucene query

Tags: lucene

WIll Lucene boolean operators works like java or C? If my query is to search for **string1 AND string2**, will Lucene first searches for string1 and then string2? And if string1 is not found in the index, will it search for string2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no short-circuiting in lucene queries. One reason for this is that search results are not a simple binary yes or no, but must be *scored* based on how strongly they match each of the terms.